# Making BoxLayout move components to top while stacking left to right

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, layout-manager

I have a `JPanel` which uses a `BoxLayout` in the `X_AXIS` direction. The problem I have is best shown by an image:
[image]

As you can see the `JPanel` on the left is has been centered rather than aligned at the top. I would like them both to be aligned at the top and stacked left to right, how can I achieve this with this layout manager? The code I have written is as follows:

```
public GameSelectionPanel(){

    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    setAlignmentY(TOP_ALIGNMENT);

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    JPanel botSelectionPanel = new JPanel();

    botSelectionPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(botSelectionPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    botSelectionPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));

    JLabel command = new JLabel("Please select your opponent:"); 

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

    JRadioButton button1 = new JRadioButton("hello world");
    JRadioButton button2 = new JRadioButton("hello world");
    JRadioButton button3 = new JRadioButton("hello world");
    JRadioButton button4 = new JRadioButton("hello world");

    group.add(button1);
    group.add(button2);
    group.add(button3);
    group.add(button4);

    botSelectionPanel.add(command);
    botSelectionPanel.add(button1);
    botSelectionPanel.add(button2);
    botSelectionPanel.add(button3);
    botSelectionPanel.add(button4);

    JPanel blindSelectionPanel = new JPanel();
    blindSelectionPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.yellow));

    blindSelectionPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(blindSelectionPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JRadioButton button5 = new JRadioButton("hello world");
    JRadioButton button6 = new JRadioButton("hello world");

    ButtonGroup group2 = new ButtonGroup();
    group2.add(button5);
    group2.add(button6);

    JLabel blindStructureQuestion = new JLabel("Please select the blind structure:");

    blindSelectionPanel.add(blindStructureQuestion);
    blindSelectionPanel.add(button5);
    blindSelectionPanel.add(button6);

    add(botSelectionPanel);
    add(blindSelectionPanel);

    setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the `setAlignmentY` method has no effect here, since it acts on the panel considered as a component.

As you have guessed, the layout of contained panels is defined by the layout manager you use.
Unfortunatly, `BoxLayout` do not provide the kind of feature you're looking at.

in standard JDK, obviously, the layout of choice for your problem is `GridBagLayout`. Although rather hard to understand at first, it will fast reveal to you its power in components arrangement.

using the useful [GBC](http://www.horstmann.com/articles/Taming_the_GridBagLayout.html) class, your components could be arranged as such :

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout(this));

add(botSelectionPanel, new GBC(0,1).setAnchor(TOP));
add(blindSelectionPanel, new GBC(0,2).setAnchor(TOP));
```

or I think so ;-)

Comment: Wow dude nice link about that GBC class. Although I started using the GridBagConstraints full constructor. I learned the parameter positions. But for small GUI's the GBC is the way to go. For larger GUI's I think the one-line full GridBagConstraints constructor is the best solution.

Comment: GridBagLayout constructor has no input paramter

Comment: your sample gives Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal anchor value

Answer (score 5):

[Riduidel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15619/riduidel) is correct about setting `setAlignmentY` on the `GameSelectionPanel` itself, and `GridBagLayout` is an excellent alternative. If you prefer to stick with `BoxLayout`, the article [*Fixing Alignment Problems*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#alignment) discusses the matter, suggesting "all the components controlled by a left-to-right Boxlayout should generally have the same Y alignment." In your example, add

```
botSelectionPanel.setAlignmentY(JPanel.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
blindSelectionPanel.setAlignmentY(JPanel.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
```